# ag-grid checkboxSelection default value

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have an ag-grid with a simple checkboxSelection and would like to have some rows "checked" when loading the grid/data.

```
{
                headerName: ' ',
                colId: 'select',
                checkboxSelection: true,
                headerCheckboxSelection: false,
                width: 22,
                maxWidth: 22,
                suppressToolPanel: true,
                suppressMenu: true,
                suppressSorting: true,
                suppressSizeToFit: true,
                suppressMovable: true,
                suppressFilter: true,
                suppressResize: true,
                pinned: 'left'
},
```

Is there a callback I can use to set the selection state of a row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to loop the rendered rows and select them manually after load:

```
this.gridApi.forEachLeafNode( (node) => {
   if (node.data.id === roleId) {
       node.setSelected(true);
   }
});
```

Comment: it selects all row, I want the only checkbox should be checked

Comment: @Manish I haven't used ag-grid in a couple years, but if you share some code I'll take a look.